# Using Java in the Gadget specification xml instead of javascript

Tags: java, opensocial

How do I develop apps that run on Orkut.com using the OpenSocial java
client libraries? I have read the OpenSocial tutorial for Orkut, and
am running the simple tutorial app on Orkut. Now I want to use Java in
the Gadget Specification XML file. Is there some sample code or
tutorial out there that explains this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gadgets for Orkut can't be written in Java, only HTML, Javascript, and css.

Comment: and maybe Flash (don't know about Orkut, but OpenSocial describes Flash support)

Comment: Orkut gadgets don't support flash.

Answer (score 2):

You could try implementing your gadget in GWT which is written in Java but then cross compiled into Javascript, Html, and CSS.  Here are a couple of pointers that may be useful:

- http://www.slideshare.net/dgirard/javapolis-gwt-gadget-opensocial
- http://knol.google.com/k/building-an-opensocial-gadget-with-gwt-hosting-on-google-code-and-putting-on#

Answer (score 0):

You can have your servlets/jsp`s on your server and access them in the app through JSON and render them in your app!